Why doesn't Brunetti eat pasta?
Why does the Brunetti family rarely eat pasta? When they do, it is usually macaroni cheese.
Is this because they are Italian? Is it because Donna Leon is American?

I think a few more details would help here. How do you know that they rarely eat pasta? Do you mean that Leon rarely describes them as eating pasta, compared to other kinds of food? Perhaps you could do a survey of eating scenes in one or two of the novels to verify this for us?

There is a Brunetti's Cookbook, just so you know.

Regards the cookbook very few  meals  apear in the books unlike the Proust  cookbook in the same series .

More info is needed. But Venetian cuisine is distinct from much of Italian food: lots of seafood and polenta. There's a lot of variation in Italian regional cuisine, although most have some variety of pasta/noodles, it may be eaten in soup rather than with an American-style sauce. I'm not familiar with the books so who knows; maybe it's just personal taste, as macaroni cheese (which is as much English as Italian in origin) may indicate.

Yes Brunetti eats lots of seafood but his sargent says he wouldn't eat anything that came out of THAT sea.
